# Selección de elementos en angular

Tags: angular, angular6

Hola tengo una tabla html simple, la creo usando *ngFor, en la tabla utilizo una referencia en el id para saber la columna y la fila en la que secuentra field1-1, field1-2, field1-2, field1-3, y así sucesivamente, en ella quiero cambiar el estilo por celda para mostrar en donde hay un error, podría utilizar

`document.getElementbyId('field1-1').style.background = 'red';`

sería muy fácil, pero no es the angular way, puedo usar la función renderer2, pero necesitaría crear elementRef por cada celda manualmente,
pero no me es conveniente.

`@ViewChild("field1-1") myButton: ElementRef;`

ya que mi función recorre el array que crea la tabla y genera una lista de errores, con las referencias hacía los Id, dinamicamente

como puedo hacer esto usando angular.

gracias!

Comment: si usas ng-if? para condicionar el error

Comment: no, los errores los estoy gestionando desde typescript, por eso me gustaría algo similar a hacer esto document.getElementbyId('field1-1').style.background = 'red';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es fáci ya que al utilizar @viewchild el decorador se puede acceder al elemento nativo y a sus hijos.

```
@ViewChild('tableData') table: ElementRef;
```

---

```
                this.renderer.setStyle(
                this.table.nativeElement.children[0].children[index + indexNum].children[0],
                'background',
                'red'
            );
```

itero sobre el elemento y voy cambiando los hijos, y utilizo renderer2 para hacer cambios de forma segura en la tabla

[aquí una referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035960/2591444)